# Securely delete a file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, security, data-recovery, secure-erase

I have been reading about government standards for secure data erasure by overwriting the file location with random data [[wikipedia: data erasure standards]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_erasure#standards). I am wondering if Ubuntu's default Delete (shift+Delete through Nautilus) implements any of these standards. What about if I'm inside an eCryptFS directory? Are there 3rd party packages that I can get through `apt-get` that add secure delete to the right-click context menu?

Comment: You could sleep much better if you used both encrypted disks and swap.

Comment: @ott-- Keys can be lost or stolen.

Comment: @ott-- I have eCryptFS on some of my users. Do you know how delete works there?

Comment: By default wipe uses random patterns to overwrite the file, so there will be no change here. A more advanced usage relies on the usage of specific patterns to make data recovery even more difficult at the magnetic level, here filesystem encryption will most probably just void this effort since these patterns will be encrypted before reaching the magnetic plate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift+Delete just avoids moving the file to the trash, however it does not do any attempt to securely delete the file.

To do a secure deletion, you can install the [Nautilus Wipe package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/nautilus-wipe). For information this is the Nautilus counterpart of the command-line [wipe package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/wipe).

Comment: Wonderful! Though having looked into `wipe`, readers should see my self-answer below for info from `wipe`'s man page indicating that `secure delete` tools are not nearly as effective as we might like to believe.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GZBK for pointing me to the [wipe package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/wipe).

For future readers in this thread, I want to quote several parts of `wipe`'s [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wipe).

> Journaling filesystems (such as Ext3 or ReiserFS) are now being used by default  by  most Linux distributions.  No secure deletion program that does filesystem-level calls can sanitize  files  on  such  filesystems, because  sensitive  data  and  metadata  can be written to the journal, which cannot be readily accessed.  Per-file secure deletion  is  better implemented in the operating system.

So if you're using a journaled fie system, then any 3rd party secure deletion program will not be as secure as you may be lead to believe. Kernel-level secure deletion routines have more direct access to the disk and may be able to bypass some of these limitations. But even for kernels...

> Be aware that harddisks are quite intelligent beasts those days. They transparently remap defective blocks. This means that the disk can keep an albeit corrupted (maybe slightly) but inaccessible and unerasable copy of some of your data. Modern disks are said to have about 100% transparent remapping capacity. You can have a look at recent discussions on Slashdot.
>
> I hereby speculate that harddisks can use the spare remapping area to secretly make copies of your data. Rising totalitarianism makes this almost a certitude. It is quite straightforward to implement some simple filtering schemes that would copy potentially interesting data. Better, a harddisk can probably detect that a given file is being wiped, and silently make a copy of it, while wiping the original as instructed.

So if you are handling highly sensitive information then you should treat the hardware of your hard disk as malicious, and only pass data to the disk in fully encrypted form by using full disk encryption in the OS. Furthermore, when discarding a drive with sensitive data on it, you should ensure that it has been properly physically destroyed (many companies offer hard drive shredding services) rather than relying on software wipes.

### Update

As pointed out by GZBK in comments below, this information appears to be out of date. In particular, it appears that the man page for `wipe` hasn't been updated since 2006.

Comment: Regarding ext3, this concern was indeed true with the first version of ext3, where data was journalised too, however this behavior [has been improved](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/FAQs/ext3-faq.html) by adding a new parameter allowing to define what should be journalised and setting it to "data=ordered" by default so only metadata will be journalised, and data will be written in place of the previous data. This parameter is a mount option which can be checked using 'dmesg' or in '/var/log/messages', and can be set using '/etc/fstab'.

Comment: Regarding bad block remapping, you can check this using SMART properties which will tell you how many blocks the disk had to remap. However, if your disk is actually beginning to find bad blocks, it is just quietly dying and you may plan to replace it asap. Magnetic disk disks are intelligent but underlying technology make wiping usually trustable (unless the NSA selected you for a firmware upgrading your disk from "intelligent" to "mean"). SSD, on the other hand, may pose [specific issues](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12503/can-wiped-ssd-data-be-recovered)...